# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{\cos\alpha x}-\sqrt[m]{\cos\beta x}}{\sin^2x},m\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{\cos\alpha x}-\sqrt[m]{\cos\beta x}}{\sin^2x},m\in \mathbb{N}$$

I used L'Hospital's rule, but that didn't work. Could Taylor series be used? I don't know how to use it with irrational functions.

Comment: Hint: The result will be $\frac{\beta^2-\alpha^2}{2m}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via the use of following standard limits $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = na^{n - 1},\,\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}} = \frac{1}{2},\,\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$ Let us proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{\cos \alpha x} - \sqrt[m]{\cos \beta x}}{\sin^{2}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{\cos \alpha x} - \sqrt[m]{\cos \beta x}}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{x^{2}}{\sin^{2}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{\cos \alpha x} - \sqrt[m]{\cos \beta x}}{x^{2}}\cdot 1\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1 - \sqrt[m]{\cos \beta x}) - (1 - \sqrt[m]{\cos \alpha x})}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1 - \sqrt[m]{\cos \beta x})}{x^{2}} - \frac{(1 - \sqrt[m]{\cos \alpha x})}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \sqrt[m]{\cos \beta x}}{1 - \cos \beta x}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos \beta x}{x^{2}} - \frac{1 - \sqrt[m]{\cos \alpha x}}{1 - \cos \alpha x}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos \alpha x}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 1}\frac{1 - t^{1/m}}{1 - t}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos \beta x}{x^{2}} - \lim_{t \to 1}\frac{1 - t^{1/m}}{1 - t}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos \alpha x}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{m}\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos \beta x}{x^{2}} - \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos \alpha x}{x^{2}}\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{m}\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\beta^{2}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos (\beta x)}{(\beta x)^{2}} - \lim_{x \to 0}\alpha^{2}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos (\alpha x)}{(\alpha x)^{2}}\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{\beta^{2}}{2} - \frac{\alpha^{2}}{2}\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{\beta^{2} - \alpha^{2}}{2m}\notag
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Use
\begin{equation}
cos(\alpha x)=1-(\alpha x)^{2}/2
\end{equation}

since $x$ is going to zero

\begin{equation}
(1-\frac{\alpha^2 x^{2}}{2})^{(1/m)}=1-(\alpha x)^{2}/2m
\end{equation}

you should do the same for $(cos(\beta x))^{1/m}$.

Obviously you can replace $sin^2x$ with $x^2$.

Therefore, the final result is: $\frac{1}{2m}(\beta^2-\alpha^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hospital's rule works.$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{\cos\alpha x}-\sqrt[m]{\cos\beta x}}{\sin^2 x}$$$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{m}\cdot (\cos\alpha x)^{\frac{1}{m}-1}\cdot (-\alpha \sin\alpha x)-\frac{1}{m}\cdot (\cos\beta x)^{\frac{1}{m}-1}\cdot (-\beta \sin\beta x)}{2\sin x\cos x}$$$$=\frac{1}{2m}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{(\cos\alpha x)^{\frac{1}{m}-1}\cdot (-\alpha \sin\alpha x)}{\alpha\beta x}-\frac{(\cos\beta x)^{\frac{1}{m}-1}\cdot (-\beta \sin\beta x)}{\alpha\beta x}}{\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\alpha\beta x}}$$$$=\frac{1}{2m}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{-\alpha(\cos\alpha x)^{\frac 1m-1}}{\beta}\cdot\frac{\sin\alpha x}{\alpha x}-\frac{-\beta (\cos\beta x)^{\frac 1m-1}}{\alpha}\cdot\frac{\sin\beta x}{\beta x}}{\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot \cos x}=\frac{-\alpha^2+\beta^2}{2m}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can observe that $a^m-b^m=(a-b)(a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}b+\dots+ab^{m-1}+b^{m-1})$; denote the second factor, for $a=\sqrt[m]{\cos\alpha x}$ and $b=\sqrt[m]{\cos\beta x}$ by $K(x)$.

Then you have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{\cos\alpha x}-\sqrt[m]{\cos\beta x}}{\sin^2x}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\alpha x-\cos\beta x}{\sin^2x\,K(x)}
$$
Now observe that $\lim_{x\to0}K(x)=m$ so you're left with
$$
\frac{1}{m}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\alpha x-\cos\beta x}{x^2}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}
$$
The second factor has limit $1$, so we can disregard it. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\alpha x-\cos\beta x}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-(\alpha x)^2/2-1+(\beta x)^2/2+o(x^2)}{x^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using 
$$\cos x \approx 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^4),\quad(1+x)^a \approx 1+ ax + \mathcal{O}(x^2),\quad \sin^2 x \approx x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^6)$$
It comes :
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sqrt[m]{\cos\alpha x}-\sqrt[m]{\cos\beta x}}{\sin^2 x} &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1 + \frac{1}{m} \left( 1 -\frac{(\alpha x)^2}{2}\right) - 1 - \frac{1}{m} \left( 1 - \frac{(\beta x)^2}{2}\right)}{x^2}\\
&= \dfrac{\beta^2 - \alpha^2}{2m}
\end{align}